# Silicon carbide in Avogadro Project

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, material-science

I am interested in an issue related to Project Avogadro. Scientists have created a silicon carbide sphere that if it was blown up to the size of Earth, the distance between the tallest mountain and deepest ocean would be just 3–5 meters (about 10–15 feet).The spheres were perfected by Achim Leistner who has an ability to feel imperfections at an atomic scale. My question is: for what purpose were these spheres created? After all, every time one touches it, it can lose several atomic layers. Isn't it the case that every time Leistner tried to sense some imperfection on its surface, he wiped billions of atoms off the sphere's surface in passing?

Comment: So Achim could feel the imperfections...

Comment: The purpose of the sphere is to try to get exactly 1 kg of silicon.

Comment: `ability to feel imperfections at an atomic scale` ... the Wikipedia article does not say that